# Will renaming the update.php file affect the Drupal update process?

Tags: updating

Will renaming the update.php file affect the Drupal update process? What's the correct way of renaming this file/path?

If we want to use /update as alias for a node, there seem to be SEO disadvantages as it's treated as a Drupal core/system URL by crawlers.

Comment: There is no correct way. As soon as you rename this, you'll be hacking core which is a no no.

Comment: You should be using the [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module, which will address your issue/concern and has other benefits.

Answer (score 1):

> Will renaming the update.php file affect the Drupal update process?
>   What's the correct way of renaming this file/path?

There is no correct way. As soon as you rename this, you'll be hacking core which is a no no.

> If we want to use /update as an alias for a node, there seem to be SEO disadvantages as it's treated as a Drupal core/system URL by crawlers.

By default Drupal already addresses this issue because of this line in [Robots.txt](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/robots.txt/7.x):

```
Disallow: /update.php
```

So no robot/spider should be crawling update.php.